# Java - Thread.join( ) does not release the lock

Tags: java, multithreading

i debug this code and i don't understand why i get deadlock. When you execute this code, it looks like the main thread lock in the join method while the other thread is waiting to acquire the lock.

```
public class Foo {

private final Thread thread;

public Foo() {
    thread = new Thread(new Bar(), "F");
    thread.start();
}

public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        thread.interrupt();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Foo run method");
    }
}

private final class Bar implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (Foo.this) {
            System.out.println("Bar run method");
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.run();
}

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you don't understand. `Thread.join()` waits for the target thread to finish. There's nothing in the Javadoc about it releasing locks. You made that up.

Comment: Please thoroughly read how thread works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `Thread.join()` doesn't release any locks. You've designed a perfectly working deadlock, where `Thread-1` is waiting for `Thread-2` to die having locked on `Foo`, and `Thread-2` is waiting to lock on `Foo`.

(Technically speaking the current implementation does release locks, as it uses internally `wait()` while synchronized on `Thread`. However that's an internal mechanism not related to user code)