# Does Thread.join() release the lock? Or continue to hold it?

Tags: java, multithreading

As I understand it, internally `obj.join()` calls `wait()`. This means that `join()` always releases the lock (because `wait()` always releases the lock after being called).

The API doc [explains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-):

> This implementation uses a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on
>   `this.isAlive`. As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is
>   invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or
>   `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

People [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842714/java-thread-join-does-not-release-the-lock) say that *`join()` does not release any lock* because the API does not mention it explicitly. But this logic seems strange to me.

Here is the main logic from `join()`'s code:

```
 while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
```

[This site](http://www.java67.com/2017/11/difference-between-wait-and-join-method-of-thread-java.html) further adds to the confusion (I think they are mistaken):

> 3) The third difference between the `wait()` and `join()` methods is that when a thread calls the `wait()` method it releases any lock held for the object on which `wait()` is called, but **calling the `join()` method doesn't release any monitor or lock.**

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  If you want to understand how `t.join()` works, it's all there in the OpenJDK source code.  If you only want to know how to use it, then you don't need to know anything about locks.  All you need to know in that case is that `t.join()` waits for thread `t` to die.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an interview question :)))

Comment: If I was asked that question in a job interview, I would make sure to show that I knew the difference between how `t.join()` might work in some implementation, and how it is supposed to be used.  The OpenJDK implementation of `t.join()` locks a lock and `wait()`s for a notification, but it is not a lock or a notification of which _client_ code should have any awareness.  Unfortunately, the lock object used by OpenJDK happens to be the `Thread` object itself, which was not a smart idea.  It would have been smarter to lock and wait on a hidden, `private` object.

Answer (score 9):

[`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) releases the monitor held on the object which `wait` is invoked on, but not any other monitors.

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits [...].

In other words, given the following:

```
synchronized (a) {
    synchronized (b) {
        b.wait();
    }
}
```

At `b.wait()`, the current thread releases `b`'s monitor, but not `a`'s monitor.

If `t.join()` is implemented using `t.wait()` internally, then `t`'s monitor is released while waiting, but not any other monitor.

This `join` implementation is a case of [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction), by the way. If `Thread` used a `private final Object monitor;` to wait on instead, we could say that `join` released no monitors, even if it used `wait` internally without us knowing. There would be no reason to document the implementation detail of using `wait`, because the monitor would be inaccessible to us, so we would not need to know about it.

The reason that we know `join` uses `wait` internally is that the people who originally wrote the method chose a monitor which is accessible to us. This created the need to reveal the implementation details. `join` is not really *supposed* to release monitors from our perspective, just wait for a thread to complete, but an implementation was chosen which required us to know more about it than we should.

Answer (score 2):

Though the excellent answer from @Radiodef clarifies & elaborates the leaky abstraction shortcoming, in simpler terms to answer @vrinchvucz confusion the answer is,

Yes, when a thread invokes `t.join` it does acquire and release 'a' monitor lock. That monitor lock is that of the thread `t` itself since the implementation of join method on Thread class implemented it by using `this.wait` inside of the `synchronized` `join` method which is the leaky abstraction issue that @Radiodef points to.

Thus unless the thread acquires the monitor lock of `t` itself before it invokes `t.join` we can say that NO client/user acquired monitor locks are released in the `t.join` invocation (because the monitor lock in question is NOT any that the client/user code acquired in the thread that invoked `t.join`).

This since as clearly stated in the docs for [Object#wait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-)

> Note that the wait method, as it places the current thread into the
>   wait set for this object, unlocks only this object; any other objects
>   on which the current thread may be synchronized remain locked while
>   the thread waits.

Which is why the docs for `Thread#join` does not mention anything about locks being released while still giving the implementation details regarding the use of `this.wait`.